# Regex XML tags having angle brackets inside

Tags: java, regex, xml

I need a regex which will give me one XML tag e.g. `<ABC/>` or `<ABC></ABC>`

So, here if I use `<(.)+?>`, it will give me `<ABC>` or `<ABC>` or `</ABC>`. This is fine.

Now, the problem:

I have one XML as

```
<VALUE ABC="10000" PQR="12422700" ADJ="" PROD_TYPE="COCOG EFI LWL P&amp;C >1Y-5Y" SRC="BASE" DATA="data" ACTION="INSERT" ID="100000" GRC_PROD=""/>
```

Here, if you see, `PROD_TYPE="COCOG EFI LWL P&amp;C >1Y-5Y"` has a greater than symbol in the value of an attribute.

So, the regex returns me

`<VALUE ABC="10000" PQR="12422700" ADJ="" PROD_TYPE="COCOG EFI LWL P&amp;C >`

instead of complete

`<VALUE ABC="10000" PQR="12422700" ADJ="" PROD_TYPE="COCOG EFI LWL P&amp;C >1Y-5Y" SRC="BASE" DATA="data" ACTION="INSERT" ID="100000" GRC_PROD=""/>`

**I need some regex which will not consider the less than and greater than symbols which are part of value i.e. enclosed in double quotes.**

Comment: Just this one: <.+> ?!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
(?i)<[a-z][\w:-]+(?: [a-z][\w:-]+="[^"]*")*/?>
```

And the explanation goes here below:

```
(?i)         # Match the remainder of the regex with the options: case insensitive (i)
<            # Match the character “<” literally
[a-z]        # Match a single character in the range between “a” and “z”
[\\w:-]       # Match a single character present in the list below
                # A word character (letters, digits, and underscores)
                # The character “:”
                # The character “-”
   +            # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
(?:          # Match the regular expression below
   \\            # Match the character “ ” literally
   [a-z]        # Match a single character in the range between “a” and “z”
   [\\w:-]       # Match a single character present in the list below
                   # A word character (letters, digits, and underscores)
                   # The character “:”
                   # The character “-”
      +            # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   =\"           # Match the characters “=\"” literally
   [^\"]         # Match any character that is NOT a “\"”
      *            # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   \"            # Match the character “\"” literally
)*           # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
/            # Match the character “/” literally
   ?            # Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>            # Match the character “>” literally
```

And if you like like to include `open`, `close` or `self-closed` tags then try below `RegEx`:

```
(?i)(?:<([a-z][\w:-]+)(?: [a-z][\w:-]+="[^"]*")*>.+?</\1>|<([a-z][\w:-]+)(?: [a-z][\w:-]+="[^"]*")*/>)
```

A `java` code frag implementing the same:

```
try {
    boolean foundMatch = subjectString.matches("(?i)(?:<([a-z][\\w:-]+)(?: [a-z][\\w:-]+=\"[^\"]*\")*>.+?</\\1>|<([a-z][\\w:-]+)(?: [a-z][\\w:-]+=\"[^\"]*\")*/>)");
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I just changed this to 

(?i)</?[a-z][\w:-]+(?: [a-z][\w:-]+="[^"]*")*/?>

as it was not checking for forward slash at start.

Comment: Glad to help...but doing so, it would not match `<ABC>...</ABC>` in a single hit...!!as you mentioned in the question...

Comment: I don't need them to be matched in one but need them seperate. Thanks anyways! :)

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the point of G_H’s link:  [Don't use regex to parse XML.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)  Use [XPath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html) to return a Node, and pass that Node to an identity [Transformer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html):

```
Node valueElement = (Node)
    XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath().evaluate("//VALUE",
        new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlDocument)),
        XPathConstants.NODE);

StringWriter result = new StringWriter();
TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(
    new DOMSource(valueElement), new StreamResult(result));

String valueElementMarkup = result.toString();
```

Comment: +1, Nice approach...though not tested yet...btw what about if `xname` contains a `namesoace`...how to handle that?

Comment: @Cylian I think an XPath of `"//*[local-name()='VALUE']"` would do the trick.

Comment: @Cylian I'm not a .Net expert, but it sure looks like [.Net supports it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb63z0tw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  I'm not sure what you mean by browsers;  are you talking about JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Also try this:

`<.*?(".*?".*?)*?>`

It grabs everything between `<` and `>` only if even number of `"` double quotes are present. Pairs of double quotes mean that stuff is enclosed in. Otherwise it skips `>` symbol and keep searching further for the next one `>` (which should be happen after closing `"` quote)